# how to avoid image captured repeatedly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, face-recognition

I'm new in android development.I'm currently developing an apps that comparing image from  id card with the image of face.From `UploadActivity`,user will capture id card and after click "OK" user will be prompted to live front camera from `LivenessActivity` to capture user's face .Supposedly after doing movement which is blink eyes ,face will be successfully captured and automatically prompt the `UploadActivity`.In the `UploadActivity`,user will click button "VIEWFACE" and the image of face will appear.But unfortunately,during capturing face image,the `LivenessActivity` keeps appearing to ask user capturing again .But if user click back button ,then it will prompt `UploadActivity`.How to avoid the `LivenessActivity` keep appearing after capture face?

This is my `Upload Activity` and `LivenessActivity` for your reference:

**UploadActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    imgFace = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFace);
    btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);



    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            captureImage();
        }

    });



    Intent i = getIntent();

    // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
    final boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage",true);
    previewMedia(isImage);
    if (fileUri != null)



      //call LivenessActivity
        startActivity(new Intent(UploadActivity.this,
        LivenessActivity.class));


    btnviewface = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnviewface);
    btnviewface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            byte[] face = extras.getByteArray("image_best");

            //save byte[] in the sd card, make a folder
            try {
                Config.IMAGE_FACE = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Android 
          File Upload/IMG_face.jpg";
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream( 
          Config.IMAGE_FACE);
                stream.write(face);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(face, 0, 
          face.length);
            imgFace.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            previewMedia(isImage);
            new UploadFileToServer(Config.IMAGE_DOC, 
        Config.IMAGE_FACE).execute();

        }

    } );
```

**LivenessActivity:**

```
@Override
public Detector.DetectionType onDetectionSuccess(DetectionFrame validFrame) {

    FaceIDDataStruct dataStruct = mDetector.getFaceIDDataStruct();
    if (dataStruct != null) {
        face = dataStruct.images.get("image_best");

        Intent intent = new Intent(LivenessActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
        //facefileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        //intent.putExtra("filePath", facefileUri.getPath());
        intent.putExtra("image_best",face);
        setResult(PAGE_INTO_LIVENESS, intent);

        startActivity(intent);

    }

    if (face == null) {
        face = validFrame.getCroppedFaceImageData();
    }//do something with liveness face
return DetectionType.DONE;

}
```

Comment: Hi ann.kdr please check my answer, Is it resolved for you?

Comment: yes.I've already do as you told.I put finish(); and it's works.Thank you @NaveenKumarM

Comment: Okay Great!. Then can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove startActivity in `LivenessActivity` instead of this call `finish()` or `LivenessActivity.this.finish()`

```
@Override
public Detector.DetectionType onDetectionSuccess(DetectionFrame validFrame) {

    FaceIDDataStruct dataStruct = mDetector.getFaceIDDataStruct();
    if (dataStruct != null) {
        face = dataStruct.images.get("image_best");

        Intent intent = new Intent(LivenessActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
        //facefileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        //intent.putExtra("filePath", facefileUri.getPath());
        intent.putExtra("image_best",face);
        setResult(PAGE_INTO_LIVENESS, intent);

        startActivity(intent); // Remove this
        finish(); // LivenessActivity.this.finish()

    }

    if (face == null) {
        face = validFrame.getCroppedFaceImageData();
    }//do something with liveness face
return DetectionType.DONE;

}
```